# How to fit data for TfIDFVectorizer in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to run the following code in Python:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

#define vectorizer parameters
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8, max_features=200000,
                             min_df=0.2, stop_words='english',
                             use_idf=True, tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem, 
                              ngram_range=(1,3))

%time tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(synopses) #fit the 
 vectorizer to synopses

print(tfidf_matrix.shape)
```

However I get a syntax error for the '%' symbol. How do I get around this?

Note that synopses is just a list of strings for example ['A had a good time', 'A had a bad time then left']

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42972240/tfidf-vectorizer-process-shows-error
Have you looked at this before .

Comment: When I change it to fit that implementation I get the following error:

ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or unicode string.

Comment: does this mean there is an item in synopses with the value np.nan?

Comment: Yes. that is exactly what it means.

Comment: Thanks I have fixed it now. It turns out that not all items in synopses were strings. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.